# How do I replace values in 2D numpy array using a dictionary of {value:(row#,column#)} pairs

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

```
 import numpy as np
```

the array looks like so:

```
 array = np.zeros((10,10))
 array = 
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

the dictionary is like this:

```
 dict = {72: (3, 4), 11: (1, 5), 10: (2, 4), 43: (2, 3), 22: (24,35), 11: (8, 9)}
```

I want to iterate over the array and replace any grid points that match the grid coordinates in the dictionary with the corresponding value in the dictionary

i am after an output like this:

```
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 11.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. 43. 10.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0. 72.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 11.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

** i have edited the question the provide co-ordinates that sit within the array except for 1 exception. I also provided an example of the desired output

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: you probably mean "_..in the dictionary **values** with the corresponding **keys**_" right ? The values are the tuples (coordinates), the keys are what comes before the semicolon (`:`). Note that in your example here, all coordinates in the dictionary are not in the array.

Comment: 1) yes, i meant to say keys when i said value. apologies, 2) also, i forgot to scale down my co-ordinates when i put that 10x10 array in the question. i of course felt that posting 50x50 would be too big to post

Comment: How do you get the dict? because if values can be non unique it cannot be treated as a dictionary that easily

Comment: So it's supposed to ignore the (24,35) entry?

Comment: What output should `{72: (3, 4), 11: (3, 4)}` give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to invert mapping from values=>coordinates to co-ordinates=>values before replacement in the array. I have edited the dictionary entries for demo purpose and as pointed in comments, dictionary co-ordinate entries should be less than dimensions of array

```
import numpy as np



arrObj = np.zeros((10,10))
arrObj

# [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
# [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
# [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
# [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
# [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
# [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
# [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
# [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
# [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
# [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]

#copy of array for replacement
replaceArrObj=arrObj 


#ensure co-ordinates in the dictionary could be indexed in array
#current mapping: values => co-ordinates
dictObj = {1.0:(0.0,0.0),2.0:(1.0,1.0),3.0: (2.0, 2.0), 4.0: (3.0, 3.0),5.0:(4.0,4.0), 6.0: (5.0, 5.0), 7.0: (6.0, 6.0), 8.0: (7.0,7.0), 9.0: (8.0,8.0),
10.0: (9.0,9.0)}
dictObj
#{1.0: (0.0, 0.0),
# 2.0: (1.0, 1.0),
# 3.0: (2.0, 2.0),
# 4.0: (3.0, 3.0),
# 5.0: (4.0, 4.0),
# 6.0: (5.0, 5.0),
# 7.0: (6.0, 6.0),
# 8.0: (7.0, 7.0),
# 9.0: (8.0, 8.0),
# 10.0: (9.0, 9.0)}
```

**Invert Mapping:**

```
#invert mapping of dictionary: co-ordinates => values
inv_dictObj = {v: k for k, v in dictObj.items()}
inv_dictObj
#{(0.0, 0.0): 1.0,
# (1.0, 1.0): 2.0,
# (2.0, 2.0): 3.0,
# (3.0, 3.0): 4.0,
# (4.0, 4.0): 5.0,
# (5.0, 5.0): 6.0,
# (6.0, 6.0): 7.0,
# (7.0, 7.0): 8.0,
# (8.0, 8.0): 9.0,
# (9.0, 9.0): 10.0}
```

**Replacement:**

```
#Replace values from dictionary at correponding co-ordiantes
for i,j in inv_dictObj.keys():
    replaceArrObj[i,j]=inv_dictObj[(i,j)]



replaceArrObj
#array([[  1.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
#       [  0.,   2.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
#       [  0.,   0.,   3.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
#       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   4.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
#       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   5.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
#       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   6.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
#       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   7.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
#       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   8.,   0.,   0.],
#       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   9.,   0.],
#       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  10.]])
```

**Type Conversion:**

You should not face any errors/warnings as long as both array co-ordinates and dictionary entries have same type.
    You can additionally enforce specific type conversion if you prefer int/float

```
#float to int conversion in array

replaceArrObj.astype(int)
#array([[ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
#       [ 0,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
#       [ 0,  0,  3,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
#       [ 0,  0,  0,  4,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
#       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  5,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
#       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  6,  0,  0,  0,  0],
#       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  7,  0,  0,  0],
#       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  8,  0,  0],
#       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9,  0],
#       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 10]])


#float to int conversion in dictionary, where k referes to key items and v to value items

int_dictObj = { (int(k[0]),int(k[1])):int(v) for k,v in inv_dictObj.items()}
int_dictObj
#{(0, 0): 1,
# (1, 1): 2,
# (2, 2): 3,
# (3, 3): 4,
# (4, 4): 5,
# (5, 5): 6,
# (6, 6): 7,
# (7, 7): 8,
# (8, 8): 9,
# (9, 9): 10}
```

Comment: In the comments Eric has mentioned this input  `{72: (3, 4), 11: (3, 4)}`. Is this input possible and if so what output do you expect

Comment: it's not possible. so i should have left it out. all the co-ordinates in my real dataset are within the range of the array. I'm actually working with a 100x100 array and the co-ordinates are real latitude and longitude points that have been interpolated to a scale of 0 - 100

Comment: If you have no further queries, you could close the question by accepting a solution which best serves your needs.

Comment: the example dictionary i gave has co-ordinates that are integers. the one you used to provide a solution has floating number co-ordinates. is this difference important when working with a numpy array?

Comment: I am not aware of run time type casting and internal workings of numpy arrays but personally, I would ensure type matching between array entries and dictionary items to avoid potential errors/warnings. Have edited the post to type cast float to int, replacing `int()` calls   by `float` is straightforward for counter scenario.

Answer (score 3):

I hope I understood your question correctly

```
array = np.zeros((10,10))
data = {72: (3, 4), 11: (1, 5), 10: (2, 4), 43: (2, 3), 22: (24,35)}

for i in data.keys():
    try:
        array[data[i][0],data[i][1]] = float(i)
    except IndexError:
       pass
print array
```

I changed the indices such that it fits into your 10 x 10 array (I assume you work with a bigger array in your real example)

I iterate over all keys in the dictionary (the values). The program then tries to set this value in the array at the given coordinates.
I pass IndexErrors for the case some coordinates are outside the array (like the last in this example.

**EDIT**

This solution only works if your keys are unique. If they are not I would recommend the solution of @Osssan.

Comment: I overlooked uniqueness, thanks for noting this.Co-ordinates will always be unique, values might not be.

Comment: unfortunately my keys are not all unique. this is a histogram output so there are co-ordinates that have the same key. also several co-ordinates have zero keys

Comment: Please note that a dict has structure `{key:value}`, it is also possible to invert this relationship and have new dictionary mapping `{value:key}`. LHS item is referred to as key and RHS item as value. In your case, several co-ordinates will have same values i.e. values are not unique, but co-ordinates will be unique. In my solution I have transformed your dictionary into one based on co-ordinates, hence should work for your case. Could you please try and report if any issues

Comment: `data[i][0],data[i][1]` is much better spelt `data[i]`