# Filling a 2D Numpy array based on given coordinates

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to fill a 2D numpy array created by this:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.full((10,10),0)
```

Example coordinates:

[image]

How can I fill those selected elements with data even if the coordinates is switched from `2,1:2,5` to `2,5:2,1` or from `5,1:8,1` to `8,1:5,1`

If I want to fill data on `2,1 : 2,5`,`2,1 2,2 2,3 2,4 2,5` will be filled. Also same as `5,1 : 5,8`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I replace values in 2D numpy array using a dictionary of {value:(row#,column#)} pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39449394/how-do-i-replace-values-in-2d-numpy-array-using-a-dictionary-of-valuerow-col)

Comment: What about `a[1:6, 2] = 1; a[1, 5:9] = 2` doesn't do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
import numpy as np

coords = ['2,1:2,5', '8,6:4,6', '5,1:8,1']
arr = np.full((10, 10), 0)

for coord in coords:
    start, stop = map(lambda x: x.split(','), coord.split(':'))
    (x0, y0), (x1, y1) = sorted([start, stop])
    arr[int(y0):int(y1)+1, int(x0):int(x1)+1] = 1
```

Which results in `arr` looking like:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: How would you get the size of filled item? For '2,1:2,5' it's 5

Comment: @JFetz2191 It would be `int(x1) - int(x0) + int(y1) - int(y0) + 1`.

Comment: @kwinkunks if im NOT wrong, it would actually be sqrt((int(x1)-int(x0))**2+(int(y1)-int(y0))**2). Coordinate geometry ;)